# Present on an insecure (http://) my local site

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In my wordpress local site generating an error that is given below that i need to fix. so please suggest me what should i do?

error is **Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.**

[image]

Comment: The obvious solution would be to use https.

Comment: Actually, it is not an error at all, it is just a "notice" message. It basically says that if you don't use a secure connection (https) the data can be stolen.

Comment: i know this stuffs but it necessary to use the https:// connection.previously i haven't use the https:// for input type="password" fields and no such notice found. is there any changes this .js send my password data for hacking purpose.

Comment: *"Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.
Introduced in Firefox 26. Pages containing login forms must be served over HTTPS, not HTTP."* from https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Tools/Web_Console